# Can I generate multiple wallet addresses using one keystore?

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I am trying to generate multiple wallet addresses using single keystore file. Can someone please advise me if it is possible? OR one keystore can only have one wallet address?

I generate keystore and account simply by using following code

```
ks      := keystore.NewKeyStore("./dir", keystore.StandardScryptN, keystore.StandardScryptP)

// Create a new account with the specified encryption passphrase
newAcc, err     := ks.NewAccount(password)

// Return address & array
return newAcc.Address.String(), err
```

Issue that I am facing is that each time a new file is created due to function `NewKeyStore`. I am unable to find a suitable function in `keystore.go` that takes filename as path

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Keystores from go-ethereum can only contain one wallet key pair per file. To generate keystores first you must invoke `NewKeyStore` giving it the directory path to save the keystores. After you may generate a new wallet by calling the method `NewAccount` passing it a password for encryption. Every time you call `NewAccount` it will generate a new keystore file on disk.

Here's a full example of generating a new keystore account:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore"
)

func main() {
    ks := keystore.NewKeyStore("./wallets", keystore.StandardScryptN, keystore.StandardScryptP)
    password := "secret"
    account, err := ks.NewAccount(password)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(account.Address.Hex()) // 0x20F8D42FB0F667F2E53930fed426f225752453b3
}
```

Now to import your keystore is not really intuitive and I'm hoping someone can change the flow of this, or if someone knows of a better way, but basically you need to invoke `NewKeyStore` again as usual and then call the `Import` method which accepts the keystore JSON data as bytes. The second argument is the password used to encrypt it in order to decrypt it. The third argument is to specify a new encryption password but we'll use the same one in the example. Importing the account will give you access to the account as expected but it'll generate a new keystore file! There's no point in having two of the same thing so we'll delete the old one.

Here's a full example of importing a keystore and accessing the account.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore"
)

func main() {
    file := "./wallets/UTC--2018-07-04T09-58-30.122808598Z--20f8d42fb0f667f2e53930fed426f225752453b3"
    ks := keystore.NewKeyStore("./tmp", keystore.StandardScryptN, keystore.StandardScryptP)
    jsonBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    password := "secret"
    account, err := ks.Import(jsonBytes, password, password)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(account.Address.Hex()) // 0x20F8D42FB0F667F2E53930fed426f225752453b3

    if err := os.Remove(file); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

This is the way I'm able to restore the keystore but I'm hoping someone can shine some light on a cleaner way.